# Digitizing map into three dimension?

Tags: 3d, software-recommendations, 3d-map

Can somebody help me in making 3-dimensional map from 2-dimensional??some software reference or some tool which can do this. I know the height of the building and other aspects....

Comment: Is this what you are looking for: http://kodex.tumblr.com/post/37038839550/visualising-qgis-data-with-blender

Comment: Sir I want to to make 3d map from 2d map and will render it on any software which support 3d maps i.e I want to raise the height of buildings

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [OSM Buildings](http://osmbuildings.org/examples/?lat=52.52157&lon=13.41088&zoom=16). It's works with [Leaflet](http://leafletjs.com/) and [Openlayers](http://openlayers.org/).

[Here](http://tomholderness.wordpress.com/2012/12/12/3DLondon/) you'll find a short introduction of a implementation with building data stored in PostGIS.

There also exist some 3D-Mapping libraries based on WebGL:

- [OpenWebGlobe](http://www.openwebglobe.org/)
- [Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/index.html)
- [WebGL Earth](http://www.webglearth.org/)

Answer (score 1):

Grass GIS v.to.3d function is one solution. Based on a height values it makes 3D vectors. Than you can use Grass Nvis to view the data.

Other option is to script a rendering pipeline. whose the first steep is to transform 2d vetors to 3d objects.

The complex way is to use a software like Blender 3d.
The easy way is to make a script that extrude the polygons based on vertice coordinates.

To display the data I would go for WebGL solution like the ones @Basti listed,
[Cesium](http://cesiumjs.org/) is specially promising.

BTW, Cesium has a [PolygonGeometry](http://cesiumjs.org/Cesium/Build/Documentation/PolygonGeometry.html) with generates polygons from 2d coordinates.